# JButton will work but won't display my icon when it is clicked on

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have a buttonlistener that removes the TextFields and the StartButton when it is clicked, but the last part of the code that tells it to run a method that is supposed to display the icon is screwing up only at the end, but is still deleting the TextFields and the JButton. Please help.

```
public class TypeInNames extends JApplet{

  JButton StartButton;
  JTextField name1, name2;
  String player1, player2;
  String reply;
  boolean test = false;
  ImageIcon myIcon;

  Container cp = getContentPane();

     public void init() 
     {
         setSize(350, 400);
         setLayout(null);

         cp.setBackground(Color.black);

         StartButton = new JButton("Start Game!");
         name1 = new JTextField("Player 1",35);
         name2 = new JTextField("Player 2",35);
         //(x, y, width, height);
         StartButton.setBounds(115,200,120,30);
         name1.setBounds(115,140,120,20);
         name2.setBounds(115,170,120,20);

         startGame();
     }

     public void startGame()
     {
         add(StartButton);
         add(name1);
         add(name2);

         StartButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
     }

     public void game()
     {

     }

     public void endGame()
     {
         myIcon = new ImageIcon("portal-cake.jpg");
         test = true;
         repaint();
     }

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paint(g);
         if(test)
             myIcon.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
     }

     private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
         {
             if (event.getSource() == StartButton)
             {
                 player1 = name1.getText();
                 player2 = name2.getText();
                 remove(StartButton);
                 remove(name1);
                 remove(name2);

                 endGame();
             }
         }

     }



 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to override `paintComponent()` at all. Just use a `JLabel` and set the layout.

```
public void endGame() {
    myIcon = new ImageIcon("portal-cake.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(myIcon);
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    this.add(label);
    this.validate();
}
```

Addendum: Here's an alternate approach to collecting startup information.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TypeInNames extends JApplet {

    JTextField name1 = new JTextField("Player 1", 35);
    JTextField name2 = new JTextField("Player 2", 35);

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        Icon myIcon = new ImageIcon("portal-cake.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(myIcon);
        this.add(label);
        startGame();
    }

    private void startGame() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Player 1:"));
        panel.add(name1);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Player 2:"));
        panel.add(name2);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
            this, panel, "Click OK to Start",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("Selected:"
                + " " + name1.getText()
                + " " + name2.getText());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cancelled");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. the image still isn't showing up, though. do you think it might have something to do with having a solid black background in my applet?

Comment: @yodasoja: I don't think so, unless you're still calling `paint()` in `paintComponent()`. You should delete your `paintComponent()` method. If you can't delete it entirely, switch to `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Comment: Oh, okay! I finally got it to work, thank you very much mr.trashgod

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you meant to override `paintComponenet` and not `paint`?  Considering you're calling `super.paint(g)`, I'd look there first.

Comment: Good catch on the errant super method, but "Swing programs should override paintComponent() instead of overriding paint()."—http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks